# ActiveRecord order by association count but scoped to user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

Rails 5: I want to order by an association count BUT on only on associations with a specific condition (scoped to user ID in this case). I also want to retain records for which there are no associations.

**Context:**

`Users` have many `companies` via `user_companies`.

`Companies` have many `people`, `people` belong to `companies`.

`People` have many `contacts`, `contacts` belong to `people` and `users`

Example query I'm working with right now:

```
user.user_companies
  .left_joins(company: { people: :contacts })
  .group("user_companies.id")
  .order('COUNT(contacts.id) DESC')
```

**Goal:**

I want to get a list of all of a User's companies and order them by how many contacts that user has at that company.

**Problem:**

The problem is it's sorting based on *how many contacts exist for that company across the site*, not scoped to the user. As in, user A has 2 contacts at company X, but if user B has 1000 contacts at company X, then company X always shows up at the top for user A, not at the bottom.

If I add `.where('contacts.user_id = ?', user.id)`, it seems to work, but then my list no longer contains companies in which the user has 0 contacts. So it's possible that this is actually a `joins` issue and not a `order` issue.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

May be subquery will do the job?

```rb
# seeds.rb

# [Person, User, Company, Contact].each { |model| model.destroy_all }

10.times do |t|
  Company.create!({ name: SecureRandom.uuid })
end

10.times do |t|
  User.create!({
    first_name: SecureRandom.uuid,
    last_name: SecureRandom.uuid,
    companies: 3.times.map { |t| Company.order("RANDOM()").first }
  })
end

10.times do |t|
  person = Person.create!({
    first_name: SecureRandom.uuid,
    last_name: SecureRandom.uuid,
    company: Company.order("RANDOM()").first
  })
  3.times do |t|
    person.contacts.create!(user: User.order("RANDOM()").first)
  end
end

user = User.first

res = user
      .users_companies
      .select('
        users_companies.*,
        (
           select count(contacts.id)
           from contacts
           inner join people on people.id = contacts.person_id
           inner join companies on companies.id = people.company_id
           where companies.id = users_companies.id
        ) AS cnt
      ')
      .order('cnt DESC')

p res.inspect
```

```rb
class CreateCompanies < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :companies do |t|
      t.string :name

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

```rb
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :first_name
      t.string :last_name
      t.references :company, foreign_key: true

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

```rb
class CreatePeople < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :people do |t|
      t.string :first_name
      t.string :last_name
      t.references :company, foreign_key: true

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

```rb
class CreateContacts < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :contacts do |t|
      t.references :person, foreign_key: true
      t.references :user, foreign_key: true

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

```rb
class CreateUsersCompanies < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :users_companies do |t|
      t.references :user, foreign_key: true
      t.references :company, foreign_key: true

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

```rb
class Company < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :people, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :users_companies, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :users, through: :users_companies
end
```

```rb
class Contact < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :person
  belongs_to :user
end
```

```rb
class Person < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :contacts, dependent: :destroy
  belongs_to :company
end
```

```rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :users_companies, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :companies, through: :users_companies
end
```

```rb
class UsersCompany < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :company
end
```